# Wiskerplots are not clear enough to analyze data

Tags: python, analytics

I'm trying to analyze a set of costs using python.
The columns in the data frame are,

'TotalCharges', 'TotalPayments', 'TotalDirectVariableCost', 'TotalDirectFixedCost', 'TotalIndirectVariableCost', 'TotalIndirectFixedCost.

When I tried to plot them using the whisker plots, this is how they could display

[image]

[image]

I need to properly analyze these data and understand their behavior.
The following are my questions.

1. Is there any way that I can use wisker plots more clearly?
2. I believe since these are costs, we cannot ignore them as outliars. So keeping the data as it is what else I can use to represent data more clearly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you could do:

- larger print area
- rotate the axis
- plot one axis log scale

That said, I think you should examine once again your understanding of what a box and whisker plot is for.

Additionally, you might consider posting this on the Math or Cross Validated site as this doesn't have much to do with code.